# How can i change viewpager2 default page through button click?

Tags: java, android, button, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I Create a viewpager2. There has 5 page and fast page has default. I create a button in another activity and i want when i click the button then it go to viewpage2 and show as default second page. How can i do it?

Comment: you mean position of item  in viewpager??Also Please Elaborate your question properly!!

Comment: Please follow [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the active tab of ViewPager2 programmatically then use :

```
viewPager2.setCurrentItem(1 /* your tab index */)
```